# Cataloging online resources on common topic

Tags: web-apps

I have people playing bridge card game. It's happening offline but sometimes some data from a match is made online. In most of the times it's a video recording (YouTube in most of the cases, can be more than one video) and table result (a webpage) and sometimes play data (a file available online). 
I'd like to catalog the data and tag the entries properly (specifically with player names).

The result would be a database in which I could easily find all video recordings (and other data) on a given player either by providing his name or player's code.

I'd like the system to warn users before submitting content that's already in the database (e.g. checking with other YouTube video IDs) and help with filling the names of the players.

I probably prefer something open source but I can pay for it if it's worth. It does not have to feature everything I need - I can do some coding if needed but I'd like to have at leas some kind of a base for the app - not to write everything from the scratch.